# Automatic deployment from development server to Remote server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, pipeline

I'm doing an automatic deployment to move binaries,sql scripts,properties files from development server to staging server. Note, my case property and xsd files were present in the Hard Drive on the computer instead of Tomcat web server.

Jenkins has the ability to deploy applications on tomcat with the help of SVN.

How Jenkins will execute sql scripts and apply property files changes on remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major options:

- Use the Execute shell or Execute Windows batch command build steps
- use a java based tool like liquibase, ant tasks, maven plugin or many more.

Comment: Just as Miglen said. Jenkins has a lot of plugins, but they are all meant to solve *someone else's* requirements. When you have custom deployment requirements, you will have to write your own script to do that (shell, batch, ant, maven, etc) and have Jenkins execute that with parameters.